# Are SPATIAL Geometry indices performance dependant on the size and density of geometry shapes?

Tags: mysql, spatial, spatial-index, mbr

## Spatial Indexes

Given a spatial index, is the index utility, that is to say the overall performance of the index, only as good as the overall geometrys.

For example, if I were to take a million geometry data types and insert them into a table so that their relative points are densely located to one another, does this make this index perform better to identical geometry shapes whose relative location might be significantly more sparse.

## Question 1

For example, take these two geometry shapes.

### Situation 1

```
LINESTRING(0 0,1 1,2 2)
LINESTRING(1 1,2 2,3 3)
```

Geometrically they are identical, but their coordinates are off by a single point.  Imagine this was repeated one million times.

Now take this situation,

### Situation 2

```
LINESTRING(0 0,1 1,2 2)
LINESTRING(1000000 1000000,1000001 10000001,1000002 1000002)
LINESTRING(2000000 2000000,2000001 20000001,2000002 2000002)
LINESTRING(3000000 3000000,3000001 30000001,3000002 3000002)
```

In the above example:

- the lines dimensions are identical to the situation 1,
- the lines are of the same number of points
- the lines have identical sizes.

However,

- **the difference** is that the lines are massively futher apart.

---

**Why is this important to me?**

The reason I ask this question is because I want to know if I should remove as much precision from my input geometries as I possibly can and reduce their density and closeness to each other as much as my application can provide without losing accuracy.

## Question 2

This question is similar to the first question, but instead of being spatially close to another geometry shape, should the shapes themselves be reduced to the smalest possible shape to describe what it is that the application requires.

For example, if I were to use a SPATIAL index on a geometry datatype to provide data on dates.
If I wanted to store a date range of two dates, I could use a datetime data type in mysql. However, what if I wanted to use a geometry type, so that I convery the date range by taking each individual date and converting it into a unix_timestamp().

For example:

```
 Date("1st January 2011") to Timestamp =  1293861600
 Date("31st January 2011") to Timestamp =  1296453600
```

Now, I could create a LINESTRING based on these two integers.

```
 LINESTRING(1293861600 0,1296453600 1)
```

If my application is actually only concerned about days, and the number of seconds isn't important for date ranges at all, should I refactor my geometries so that they are reduced to their smallest possible size in order to fulfil what they need.

So that instead of "1293861600", I would use "1293861600" / (3600 * 24), which happens to be "14975.25".

Can someone help fill in these gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting a new entry, the engine chooses the `MBR` which would be minimally extended.

By "minimally extended", the engine can mean either "area extension" or "perimeter extension", the former being default in `MySQL`.

This means that as long as your nodes have non-zero area, their absolute sizes do not matter: the larger `MBR`'s remain larger and the smaller ones remain smaller, and ultimately all nodes will end up in the same `MBR`s

These articles may be of interest to you:

- [**Overlapping ranges in MySQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/01/overlapping-ranges-mysql/)
- [**Join on overlapping date ranges**](http://explainextended.com/2010/02/01/join-on-overlapping-date-ranges/)

As for the density, the `MBR` are recalculated on page splits, and there is a high chance that all points too far away from the main cluster will be moved away on the first split to their own `MBR`. It would be large but be a parent to all outstanding points in few iterations.

This will decrease the search time for the outstanding points and will increase the search time for the cluster points by one page seek.

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi. I couldn't have asked for a more qualified person to respond :) I'm not quite sure I fully understand. Are you saying that in response to my second question, that the area does not matter, because the MBR will be the same.

Comment: @Laykes: yes, which `MBR` will have the minimal increase does not depend on the absolute values as long as the relative stay the same.

Comment: Quassnoi, offtopic from my original question, although relevant to why I actually asked the question in the first place. Is a spatial index worth using to finds geometries which ARENT "touched", or within a particular MBR. For example, in a Holiday/Hotel system, I can using a BoundingBox around my linepoints to show when rooms are populated at a certain date, but I should I use the spatial index to find rows which contain rooms which are vacant for that date? For example, find rooms vacant between 1st January to 5th January?

Comment: @Laykes: as long as the periods do not intersect within a room, you need spatial abilities for neither query. For the given date, just find the closest `start_date` before it for each room (this is possible with a `B-Tree` index) and see if the `end_date` is after the given date or not.